# Why injecting inner-class into another inner-class in the same outer-class does not work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inner-classes

I have a class which has two inner-classes inside it. I have annotated the outer class with @Service and both inner-classes with @Component. 
InnerClassA is @Autowired into OuterClass and InnerClassB is @Autowired into InnerClassA. 
Even though all three beans get initialized but innerClassB inside InnerClassA is null.

```java
@Service
public class ChatService{
    @Autowired
    private ChatServerUtils chatServerUtils;
    @Autowired
    private PushNotificationHelper pushNotificationHelper;

    @Component
    public class PushNotificationHelper{
        @Autowired
        private ChatServerUtils chatServerUtils; //this is null
        @Autowired
        private PushService pushService;

        @Async
        public void sendPushNotifications(Group group){
            Map<String, Integer> notificationData= new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, CompletableFurure<Integer>> unreadCountFutures = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Member member : group){
                CompletableFurure<Integer> unreadCountFuture = chatServerUtils.getUnreadCount(group, member);
                unreadCountFutures.put(member.getId(), unreadCountFuture);
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String, CompletableFurure<Integer>> entry : unreadCountFutures.entrySet()){
                notificationData.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get());
            }
            pushService.sendNotifications(notificationData);
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class ChatServerUtils{
        @Async
        public CompletableFuture<Integer> getUnreadCount(Group group, Member member){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**More Info:** Outer class is a chat-service which handles things related to chat users, messages and groups. There is another service to send push notifications. When a message is sent to a group I have to send push notifications to all the users in the group. Before sending the request to push notification service I have to contact external chat server and get unread message count for each group member. The API of the chat server does not support getting unread counts of all the users in single call. Since this is a time consuming process, I need to do it asynchronously. This is why I have to move those methods into separate classes (to use @Async). Except for shown method in ChatServiceUtil class there are more methods used by both PushNotificationHelper & ChatService.

Comment: Please provide  full classes code to understand the problem

Comment: Do you need to have the inner classes as inner class? With the connections between outer and both inner classes it seems a bit weird to not have each of them as their own class. If you could post some more information on how you want to use this concept of linked inner and outer classes, it might be easier to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Could you please check now? @SahilBhalla

Comment: Could you please check now? @MirkoBrandt

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `chatServerUtils` variable from your outer `ChatService` class? As `PushNotificationHelper` is encapsulated by `ChatService` it should have access to the private variables.

Aside from that I still see no reason why your code benefits from this inner-/outer class construct. You say you have multiple methods that both inner classes use from your outer class but these inner classes could still use those methods if you inject your outer class into them. To me it seems like you should have a hard look at your code's architecture and maybe rethink some of it.
If you don't want to do that, I hope my above advice helps.

Comment: I tried using ```chatServiceUtils``` from the outer class ```ChatService```, however still it was null. I suspect since ```sendPushNotifications``` is executed asynchronously, properties injected to outer class does not available. As per my knowledge spring creates a proxy of ```PushNotificationHelper```  for running it asynchronously.

Comment: My motivation to use this outer-class inner-class style is to keep the things that are related to chatService inside a single class.

Comment: I would recommend using packages for that. You can have a package named chatService and every class that is related to the chatservice is stored there. I'd use inner classes only as a small class that's just holding some variables and is solely used by the outer class. Your inner classes maybe used by other classes than your ChatService in the future and they also have quite a bit of functionality. So I would strongly recommend you have them as their own class and don't get held up by this issue for too long.

Comment: Yes. I understand now. Thank you very much @MirkoBrandt

Comment: No problem glad I could help